# android NFC detect if reading is used by another app

Tags: android, nfc

Its there a way to detect if `nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode` is using by another app or to check if the callback is no more active and another app has called the enableReaderMode`

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make sense.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))

> Limit the NFC controller to reader mode while this Activity is in the foreground.

If your App is in the foreground then any other App will be in the background and thus won't receive any callback, so the callback is always no longer active on other apps if your App is in the foreground (it might still be registered but the NFC system service won't deliver to non foreground processes).

Thus there is no API to check this as it does not make sense to check.